# Custom naming for key fields does not work in TPT(Table Per Type) strategy in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance, ef-code-first, table-per-type

I'm using EF 6.1.1 code first with `.NET 4` and `SQL Server 2008 R2` and have following classes in my project:

[image]

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Document : BaseEntity
{
    public string Number { get; set; }
}

public class OrderHeader : Document
{
    public OrderHeader()
    {
        this.OrderItems = new List<OrderItem>();
    }
    public ICollection<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
}

public class OrderItem : Document
{
    public int OrderHeaderId { get; set; }
    public virtual OrderHeader OrderHeader { get; set; }
}
```

I want to

- Use `TPT`(Table Per Type) inheritance strategy.
- **The key field of `OrderHeader` and `OrderItem` tables be `DocumentId`.**

So I defined following mapping files:

```
public class Document_Mapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Document>
{
   public Document_Mapping()
   {
        ToTable("Document");
   }
}

public class OrderHeader_Mapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<OrderHeader>
{
    public OrderHeader_Mapping()
    {
        ToTable("OrderHeader");
        Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("DocumentId");
    }
}

public class OrderItem_Mapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<OrderItem>
{
    public OrderItem_Mapping()
    {
        ToTable("OrderItem");
        Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("DocumentId");
        HasRequired(t => t.OrderHeader)
       .WithMany(t => t.OrderItems)
       .HasForeignKey(d => d.OrderHeaderId);
    }
}
```

And use them is my `DbContext` file:

```
public class MyDbContext:DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext()
        : base("name=MyContext")
    {

       Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MyDbContext>());
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new Document_Mapping());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new OrderHeader_Mapping());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new OrderItem_Mapping());
    }
    public DbSet<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OrderHeader> OrderHeaders { get; set; }
}
```

But when I run the program the created tables look like:
[image]

The generated key columns for `OrderHeader` and `OrderItem` tables are `Id`, but in mapping I defined them to be `DocumentId`.

Does any one know where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update to EF 6.1.2-beta1 or later.

This is a bug, that was fixed here: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2087

Comment: I need to `Id` be in `BaseEntity`, because I used `BaseEntity` widely in my project and supposed that it has `Id`, nevertheless I applied your mentioned change, but nothing had changed.

Comment: You can get my test project from https://www.dropbox.com/s/ud5oi13qa14p7bl/Inheritance.rar?dl=0

Comment: Is EF `6.1.2-beta2` available? I couldn't get it.

Comment: You can get it from NIghly builds, but otherwise 6.1.2-beta1 should also have the fix

Comment: It works now, with `EF 6.1.2-beta1` even if I use `BaseEntity`. Please update your answer, there is no need to remove `BaseEntity`. Thank you for your help